# Cannot connect to database ebean with play

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I am trying to connect to mssql database server using ebean with play 2.5.4. But I am getting following exception

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [ebean]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:984)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies$$FastClassByGuice$$2a7177aa.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[either dataSource or dataSourceClassName is required]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:996)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:70)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: either dataSource or dataSourceClassName is required
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:785)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConfig.toHikariConfig(HikariCPModule.scala:141)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:57)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

db properties in application.conf:

```
default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
   default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.169.81.19/CKSCore_Dev1;instance=SQLEXPRESS"
   default.user=ep_dev
   default.password="ip4@123"
   ebean.default.databasePlatform=com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.MsSqlServer2005Platform
   ebean.default="models.*"
```

Plugins.sbt file contains line

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

Build.sbt contains

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

Did anyone face this issue. Can someone help on this?

Comment: Did you use JPA? Have you configure JNDI name for data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the plugin version should be 3.0.0, try this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

And also in application.conf:

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

In play.db{} section, it should be like this:

```
play.db {
  # The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  config = "db"
  default = "default"

  # Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
  # settings by changing the prototype:
  prototype {
    # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
    #hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
    #hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
  }
}
```

In db{} section, should be like this:

```
db {
  default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev"
  default.username=root
  default.password="Pa55word"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jasondf this helped me